# How to listen to only the first scroll event on javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently working on implementing my own version of snap-scrolling using vanilla JavaScript, and while I've got it mostly working as of now, I'm having trouble handling the scroll events.

My HTML looks something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="item1"></div>
  <div id="item2"></div>
  <div id="item3"></div>
  <div id="item4"></div>
</div>
```

And my JS looks something like this:

```
var pos = 0;
var isScrolling = false;
var id = 1;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if (!isScrolling) {
    isScrolling = true;
    var curPos = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (curPos > pos) {
      // scrolling down
      if (id < 4) {
        id++;
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $('#item' + id).offset().top
        }, 500);
      }
    } else {
      // scrolling up
      if (id > 1) {
        id--;
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $('#item' + id).offset().top
        }, 500);
      }
    }
    isScrolling = false;
    pos = curPos;
  }
});
```

What currently happens is when I scroll down my mouse wheel, it will do the animation but will keep proceeding to the next divs because of the multiple scroll events being fired. How do I make it so that it only listens to the first event (whether it scrolls up or down)?

Comment: You try this http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 0):

A hacky way is to use timer:

```
var pos = 0;
var isScrolling = false;
var id = 1;
var lastScrollTime = $.now();

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ((!isScrolling)&&((($.now()-lastScrollTime)>3000)) {
    isScrolling = true;
    var curPos = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (curPos > pos) {
      // scrolling down
      if (id < 4) {
        id++;
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $('#item' + id).offset().top
        }, 500);
      }
    } else {
      // scrolling up
      if (id > 1) {
        id--;
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $('#item' + id).offset().top
        }, 500);
      }
    }
    isScrolling = false;
    pos = curPos;
    lastScrollTime = $.now();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can register one time listeners in jQuery using [`jQuery.one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/).

EDIT:
You can use the `complete` callback of `jQuery.animate` to stop/start responding to scroll events.

```
var isScrolling = false;
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    if (!isScrolling) {
        isScrolling = true;
        var curPos = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (curPos > pos) {
            // scrolling down
            if (id < 4) {
                id++;
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('#item' + id).offset().top
                }, 500,function(){
                    isScrolling = false;
                });
            }
        } else {
            // scrolling up
            if (id > 1) {
                id--;
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('#item' + id).offset().top
                }, 500,function(){
                    isScrolling = false;
                });
            }
        }
        pos = curPos;
    }
});
```

Comment: I've tried using jQuery.one, however what happens is that the animation will only happen for the first scroll, and it stops working for any subsequent ones.

Comment: I see. I must have misunderstood this. `How do I make it so that it only listens to the first event (whether it scrolls up or down)?` Can you please clarify?

Comment: There are 4 divs, and when I scroll down/up, I want it to animate/scroll to the previous/next div. However, because of multiple scroll events being registered, if I start at the top of the page and scrolled slightly down, the counter keeps going until eventually it will reach the very bottom, which I don't want.

Comment: Ah. In that case, you can use the `complete` callback in the `jQuery.animate` call to set your boolean flag `isScrolling` to false only after the animation completes. Have updated answer

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to deal with what it is known as *kinetic scrolling*.
Browsers do not provide developers a proper way to distinguish the meaningful scrolling from the inertial ones.

However, there are some attempts out there that aims to solve this issue, such as [Lethargy](https://github.com/d4nyll/lethargy).
Not 100% ideal, but very close to it.

Other than that, you can take a look at libraries like [fullPage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) where another attempt to solve the issue was made.